# About shortcut/feature in xcode 4

Tags: xcode

Hi guys (and probably girls). 
I'm newcomer to xcode land. TextMate have a feature to jump to specific file. For example if  I press cmd+t a window appears and there I can type the name of file  I'm looking for (this feature search only files in current projecet). 
When I hit enter voalla I get the file open and ready to edit.

Is there a such feature in Xcode 4 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is. `cmd + shift + o` would be the sequence.